# Arrow animation in 2D

Tags: animation, objects, bezier-curves

[image]I think I have understood the basic principles of animating an arrow traveling along a curve. My problem is that my arrow becomes twisted as it travels along the curve. What is it that I do wrong? Does it somehow has to do do with the fact that I'm working in 2D

Comment: Try changing the Twisting setting from the default Minimum to Z-UP in the Curve settings.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

**If you want your arrow to grow along the curve:**

- Give your arrow an *Array* modifier, choose *Fit Type* > *Fixed Count*, and *End Cap* > arrow like you did.
- Give your arrow a second modifier, a *Curve* modifier, and choose the Path as the *Object*.
- Now increase the amount of *Count* of your *Array*, the arrow grows along the curve.
- You can now insert keyframes so that at frame 1 of the timeline there is only one duplication and at frame X there is as many duplications as you want.
- Note that, anyway, the arrow will be messed up at the U turn of the curve, as your arrow is not subdivide, is big, and the curve is sharp. If you don't want the front of your arrow to be deformed it should be a separate object and it should move along the curve (with the method explained below).

**If you want your arrow to move along the curve:**

You gave your arrow a *Curve* modifier while, for your purpose (follow a curve without deformation) you should have given it a *Follow Path* constraint.

Right now it is behaving like it is supposed to. You've given your arrow a *Curve* modifier, which means that it follows the curve you've chosen as *Object* and it deforms along this curve. As your arrow is big and doesn't have a high poly mesh, the deformation is a bit messy. Even with a high poly mesh it won't give anything great.

If you want your arrow to follow the curve without any deformation, you need to give it a *Follow Path* constraint:

- Remove the *Follow Path* you gave to the curve (it is useless, the curve won't follow any path).
- Delete the *Curve* modifier you gave to the arrow.
- Delete the previous *Follow Path* you gave to the arrow and give it a new one.
- In this modifier click on the *Animate Path* button, and enable the *Follow Curve* option. As Blender doesn't know how you want to orientate the arrow, try different *Forward* (*X* is the good one).
- Now the arrow follows the curve without any deformation.

Now if you want to control the speed of the arrow along the curve:

- Select the curve, open the *Graph Editor* window, on the left panel (*Path* > *NurbsPath.001*), unfold *NurbsPath.001* and click on *Evaluation Time*. Open the right panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and click on the *Modifiers* tab. Delete the *Generator* modifier (*X*). You've delete the animation you've automatically generated when you created the *Follow Path* constraint you gave to the arrow, and the arrow doesn't move any more. You have to reprogram the animation.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, choose the amount of *Frames* you want. 100 by default is ok. It means you choose to segment your curve 100 times. The *Evaluation Time* will determine at what segment of your curve your arrow will be at the time you want. For example place your timeline cursor (green bar) at 1 and create a keyframe (<kbd>i</kbd>) on the *Evaluation Time* > 0.00. Now move your timeline cursor to 20, go back to the *Evaluation Time*, choose 50, and create a keyframe. Now from frame 1 to frame 20 the arrow moves from the beginning of the curve to its middle.
- If you want the animation to be linear and not smooth as it is by default, in the *Graph Editor*, press <kbd>t</kbd> and choose *Linea*r.

Comment: Ok. But I didn' add a "curve modfier"? I added an array modifier. Could you a little bit more explicit, I'm pretty new to modifiers and constraints.

Comment: you added a Curve modifier below the Array, and you don't need the Array either, Array is made to repeat an object, it's not your purpose here

Comment: Well I want the arrow to grow along the curve.

Comment: Also, If I take away the modifier, I loose the the actual arrow (there are two objects in layer 11: a "base" and the actual arrow). Please bear with me!

Comment: you should edit your question and explain precisely what you want with some drawings, so that we give you the best way to do it

Comment: and you don't have to get rid of your Array if you absolutely want to keep it, what I say is that you must use the Follow Path constraint instead of the Curve modifier

Comment: 1) I create an object out of a plane consisting of two separate pieces: a base and an arrow (with a space between)
2) Then I separate the base from the arrow, creating two separate arrows
3) I highlight the base and go to origin to geometry
4) I move the 2 objects to layer 11
5) In layer 11 I copy the base and place it in layer 1 and chose “selection to grid”
6) I also add a u-shaped curve path to work as the path for my objects
7) As I was following a tutorial, this I where I added a array modifier. I’m trying to no avail to add a follow path constrain.

Comment: PS. I did try to add an array modifier and then follow path constrain but I get lost among the settings

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I was just about to to do it. Thanks for your patience. Here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5273" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5273/)

Comment: Ok. Fine. Just one thing: As I wrote before, I wanted it to grow, meaning that expands from the base til it reaches its end point.

Comment: aaah ok so wait a bit I'll edit my answer. But note that that was note your first question

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Moonboots. As you suggested, the solution is partly to to subdivide the meshes, tho make the arrow thinner in proportion to the curve or vice verse. Strictly speaking the initial tutorial was right, although it failed to mention subdivision of the meshes. Anyway, thanks for all your patience and help.

Comment: it really depends if you want the front of the arrow to bend... if you don't want, then it should be a completely separate object and use a follow path constraint while the tail should use a curve modifier